# How do I remove the blank spaces in my csv scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, scrapy

How do I remove the blank spaces in my csv?

I run: `scrapy crawl quotes -o quotes.csv`.  And output is like that in the picture.

I know it's a windows problem as I have to use below code when working with csv's on windows.  For example when working with selenium.

```
with open('C:\\fa.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
```

Scrapy deals with Csv's differently and I launch with

```
scrapy crawl quotes -o quotes.csv

There is no: scrapy crawl quotes -o /n quotes.csv
```

Code:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
            }

        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

[image]

Comment: There's probably csv configuration of the sort in scrapy somewhere...  HMMMM.  Perhaps in the _init_ file... I can adjust that in Anaconda.. wherever it is.  Maybe that will fix.

Comment: open csv file in normal text editor and see if there are empty lines. If there are no empty lines then there is problem with program which you use to open csv file.

Comment: @furas The issue is seen in the notepad++ as well

Comment: Why do you use `newline=''` in `open()` ? It seams your data has `'\n'` and you forgot to remove it before you put in csv. Do you know `text.strip()` command ?

Comment: How would I remove/add the \n in scrapy? I am not familiar with text.strip command.  I just use newline when working with selenium as csv's in seem to create gaps

Comment: it is not scrapy problem - it is standard command in Python. ie. `"\nHello World\n".strip()`. Command `.extract_first()` gives string so you can use `.extract_first().strip()`. Command `.extract()` gives list so it need more work `"tags": [x.strip() for x in quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract()]`

Comment: @furas I followed that exactly but I still get issue https://pastebin.com/EZfz4Pn6

Comment: what is `FixLineCsvItemExporter` ? why do you use it ? maybe it makes problem.

Comment: @furas I removed it and same issue.

Comment: I run your code as standalone script (without creating project) and it saves it correctly - https://pastebin.com/YChnURsM . Maybe you have extra options in settings, maybe it uses extra `pipeline` function. Or maybe it is problem only on Windows - I run Linux.

Comment: @furas Is there a way to add: newline='', encoding="utf-8" to the pipeline?
  That would probably fix.      Aside from some weird errors, I tried your code: https://pastebin.com/NDtPMRir .  Same issue.

Comment: you can write own function to export data using [CsvItemExporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#csvitemexporter) - it seams it can send parameters to `csv.writer` - here example with [exporter which skips headers in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485789/scrapy-csv-output-without-header)

Comment: @furas While file am I looking at sorry? Or am I to create a new py file.

Comment: there is described - put code in `exporters.py` in the same folder you have `settings.py` and `items.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following fix:

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter


class FixCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        newline = settings.get('CSV_NEWLINE', '')
        kwargs['newline'] = newline
        super(FixCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, in the `settings.py` file in your crawler directory you need to add this:

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'path.to.sourcefile.FixCsvItemExporter',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution myself: [Scrapy python csv output has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472847/scrapy-python-csv-output-has-blank-lines-between-each-row)

That said, I believe there is a patch on its way at some point.