# How to strip Scrapy results before outputted to CSV

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to isolate the integer from some HTML, e.g. "
                            5,500 miles
                        ".

```
import scrapy

class AlfaShortSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alfashort'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url = 'https://www.pistonheads.com/classifieds/used-cars/alfa-romeo/giulia',
                             callback = self.parse_data)


    def parse_data( self, response ):
        advert = response.xpath( '//*[@class="ad-listing"]')
        title = advert.xpath( './/*[@class="listing-headline"]//h3/text()' ).extract()
        price = advert.xpath( './/*[@class="price"]/text()' ).extract()
        mileage = advert.xpath( './/*[@class="specs"]//li[1]/text()' ).extract()
        mileage = [item.strip() for item in mileage]
        mileage = [item.replace(',','') for item in mileage]
        mileage = [item.replace(' miles','') for item in mileage]

        for item in zip(title,price,mileage):
            price_data = {
                    'title' : item[0],
                    'price' : item[1],
                    'mileage' : item[2]
            }

            yield price_data
```

My code successfully removes the comma and "miles" but in my CSV output I get unwanted blank rows in this column which I presume are due to the carriage returns in the original source. My CSV looks like this:

[my CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7ptE.png)

So the title and price columns are fine. But the Mileage column is where the error is.

is there something wrong with my Strip command?

Comment: You could use [logging](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html) to find out at which point something unexpected happens.

Comment: You should debug what the response looks like when `milage` is empty. Maybe your request gets blocked in some way?

Comment: Does your csv look like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477662/scrapy-csv-file-has-uniform-empty-rows/43394566) ?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my CSV output. ONly the mileage column has blank rows inserted. So not only are some mileages missing, those that are in there are misaligned with the other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the XPath for mileage

from

```
mileage = advert.xpath( './/*[@class="specs"]//li[1]/text()' ).extract()
```

to

```
mileage = advert.xpath( './/*[@class="specs"]//li[1]/text()[2]' ).extract()
```

You will get output correct output:

```
title,price,mileage
ALFA ROMEO GIULIA (0) V6 BITURBO QUADRIFOGLIO                  2018 (2018),"£48,500",5500
ULEZ CHARGE EXEMPT! EURO 6  (2017),"£25,695",11450
ALFA ROMEO GIULIA (0) V6 BITURBO QUADRIFOGLIO NRING            2019 (2019),"£83,500",100
ALFA ROMEO GIULIA (0) TD SPECIALE                              2017 (2017),"£22,500",23700
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. Would you mind explaining how this works? I'm new to XPath but my understanding is that [2] selects the 2nd object of that type, but it looks to me that there is only 1 text object for each /li/

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked. In the first object, the value is blank.